# How to avoid Spring Repository<T, ID> to leak persistence information into service tier

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

*I'm using spring-data-mongodb at the moment so this question is primarily in context of MongoDB but I suspect my question applies to repository code in general.*

Out of the box when using a `MongoRepository<T, ID>` interface (or any other `Repository<T, ID>` descendent) the entity type `T` is expected to be the document type (the type that defines the document schema).

As a result injecting such a repository into service component means this repository is leaking database schema information into the service tier (highly pseudo) :

```java
class MyModel {
    UUID id;
}

@Document
class MyDocument {
    @Id
    String id;
}

interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {
}

class MyService {
    MyRepository repository;

    MyModel getById(UUID id) {
        var documentId = convert(id, ...);
        var matchingDocument = repository.findById(documentId).orElse(...);
        var model = convert(matchignDocument, ...);

        return model;
    }
}
```

Whilst ideally I'd want to do this :

```java
class MyModel {
    UUID id;
}

@Document
class MyDocument {
    @Id
    String id;
}

@Configuration
class MyMagicConversionConfig {
    ...
}

class MyDocumentToModelConverter implements Converter<MyModel, MyDocument> {
   ...
}

class MyModelToDocumentConverter implements Converter<MyDocument, MyModel> {
   ...
}

// Note that the model and the model's ID type are used in the repository declaration
interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyModel, UUID> {
}

class MyService {
    MyRepository repository;

    MyModel getById(UUID id) {
        // Repository now returns the model because it was converted upstream
        // by the mongo persistence layer.
        var matchingModel = repository.findById(documentId).orElse(...);

        return matchingModel ;
    }
}
```

Defining this conversion once seems significantly more practical than having to consistently do it throughout your service code so I suspect I'm just missing something.

But of course this requires some way to inform the mongo mapping layer to be aware of what conversion has to be applied to move between `MyModel` and `MyDocument` and to use the latter for it's actual source of mapping metadata (e.g. `@Document`, `@Id`, etc.).

I've been fiddling with custom converters but I just can't seem to make the MongoDB mapping component do the above.

My two questions are :

- Is it currently possible to define custom converters or implement callbacks that allow me to define and implement this model <-> document conversion once and abstract it away from my service tier.
- If not, what is the idiomatic way to approach cleaning this up such that the service layer can stay blissfully unaware of how or with what schema an entity is persisted? A lot of Spring Boot codebases appear to be fine with using the type that defines the database schema as their model but that seems supoptimal. Suggestions welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're blowing things a bit out of proportion. The service layer is *not* aware of the schema. It is aware of the types returned by the repository. How the properties of those are mapped onto the schema, depends on the object-document mapping. This, by default, uses the property name, as that's the most straightforward thing to do. That translation can either be customized using annotations on the document type or by registering a [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/MongoConfigurationSupport.html#fieldNamingStrategy--) with Spring Data MongoDB.

Spring Data MongoDB's [object-document mapping subsystem](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-chapter) provides [a lot of customization hooks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-configuration) that allows transforming arbitrary MongoDB documents into entities. The types which the repositories return are your domain objects that - again, only by default - are mapped onto a MongoDB document 1:1, simply because that's the most reasonable thing to do in the first place.

If really in doubt, you can [manually implement repository methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) individually that allow you to use the `MongoTemplate` API that allows you to [explicitly define the type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.query.fluent-template-api), the data should be projected into.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Isn't it just true though that the repository returning the schema type by implication means it has to deal with the database schema in some fashion? Even in my trivial but common example it has to know (and actually care about) the different type of the primary key for example. I can definitely see the argument for "yes, but you shouldn't care that much, just use the schema type as your model type" but in lieu of that I'm pretty sure even in my example the service is aware of schema details and needs to be on a practical level just to deal with the return type.

Comment: As for the customization; I guess that's basically my question. If I was able to specify a return type and customize the ORM such that is uses the schema type for the actual schema mapping with a custom conversion step in between I'd be done. I'd hugely appreciate a nudge in the right direction (i tried up to and including hooking on the various XXXCallback interfaces, creating a custom converter through Mongo config etc. but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Again: there is no schema type. Repositories persist Aggregate Roots, which – by definition – need to be identifiable and thus needs to care about the ID. That's nothing Spring Data imposed in the first place. That's fundamental DDD. If that's not what you want, you can build a repository implementation yourself based on `MongoTemplate` and manually copy data of the aggregates into what you call schema types.

Comment: I perhaps chose a poor example for my thought experiment with the primary ID. What I call (and maybe have misnomed) "schema type" is whatever type defines the persistence layer specific schema (and in the case of Spring Data MongoDB contains all the indexing, field mapping, etc metadata) so perhaps that's caused us to disconnect here.

Comment: What I call (and maybe have misnomed) "schema type" is whatever type defines the persistence layer specific schema (and in the case of Spring Data MongoDB contains all the indexing, field mapping, etc metadata)

How would you approach some aggregate root type T being persisted based on a persistence layer specific schema defined by some type D? I don't see how DDD modeling implies T == D. In fact there's pretty strong arguments against that route.

You seem very knowledgeable on the topic so I'd love to have a chat on this. If not thanks for your input and I'll leave the comments alone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like MapStruct or write your own Singleton Mapper.
Then create default methods in your repository:

```java
interface DogRepository extends MongoRepository<DogDocument, String> {
    DogDocument findById(String id);
    default DogModel dogById(String id) {
        return DogMapper.INSTANCE.toModel(
            findById(id)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I use mapstruct but this translates to highly repetitive code where you essentially declare all repository methods twice and repeat the exact same mapping step each time. There must be a better way forward.